# Http Live Streaming Cache

Tags: ios, video, http-live-streaming

If I wish to make a video which is being streamed by http live streaming available off-line, do I have to download the file separately of http live streaming or is there some sort of caching functionality?

The files are about three minutes long so I don't believe progressive downloading is an option.

Answer (score 0):

The files are delivered over http. It's typical to use a caching proxy when wanting to use and cache http assets.

The other option is to do the caching directly in the http client. In HLS the client is generally a video player that's outside your direct control, which makes a caching proxy the most reasonable approach.